# How to pass argument in middle of promise chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a promise chain as follows:

```
...

const id = "someId";

function1(id)
    .then(function2)
    .then(function3(id))
    .then(function4)
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200).send(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).end();
    });

...
```

Where function1, function2, function3, and function4 need to be called in order and each uses the result returned from the previous. The problem I am running into is that function3 requires the id parameter, but whenever I set it as shown above then the result from function3 is not passed to function4. How do I pass the id parameter to function3 **and** pass the result from function3 to function4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `function3` directly, without respecting the chain.

You have to do it this way:

```
.then(() => function3(id))
// or if you need the response from `function2`
.then(res => function3(id, res))
```

Or an alternative is to use **[.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**

```
.then(function3.bind(null, id)) // instead of null you can pass some context
```

Otherwise `function3` will need to return a function, that will be used by `.then` handler when `function2` resolves.

Comment: Would it be wise to edit the bind example above the note about modifying function 3 so that the order is `non modifying answer, not modifying answer, modifying answer`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: moving `Otherwise function3 will need to return a function, that will be used by .then handler when function2 resolves.` below `An alternative is to use .bind...`

Comment: yup. Because this way both examples with closures are at the top before talking about modifying the function. May be a good idea to also mention that what you're using is a closure to pass the id to function3 when the closure is executed

Comment: +1, though if `function3` uses `function2`'s output as in the question ("each uses the result returned from the previous"), then it might look like `.then(result => function3(result, id))` instead.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but I didn't know how `function3` was defined, so I went with what I knew, that the first argument is `id` as he was calling `function3(id)`, Anyway if it did take `function2` response, OP figured it out. And I edited the answer to reflect that.